# Polar coordinates: how to explain this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, polar-coordinates

For $N\geq 1$, let $u\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $u$ radially symmetric and $r>0$. I am trying to justify this inequality (it appears in my lecture notes):
$$\left(\int_{r}^{\infty} |u^{\prime}(s)|^p s^{N-1} ds\right)^{\frac1p} \leq \omega_N^{-\frac{1}{p}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\{0\}}|\nabla u|^p dx\right)^{\frac1p},$$
for $1<p<N$.

I guess something related to the polar coordinates has been used, but how? Could anyone please explain me?

Moreover, why one could write $\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^N$?

I hope someone could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Something is missing here. Is your function $u$ radially symmetric?

Comment: Yes,sorry, it is radially symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your equation $u'$ and $\nabla u$ stand for two different things. The first is a function of one variable and second is a function of $N$ variables so you must be missing a hypothesis.

Any point $x \in \mathbf R^N$ can be expressed as $x = s \omega$ where $s > 0$ and $\omega$ is a point on the unit sphere $\mathbf S^{N-1}$.  The change of variable formula reads
$$\int_{\mathbf R^N} F(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbf S^{N-1}} \int_0^\infty F(s\omega) s^{N-1} \, ds d\omega$$ for suitable functions $F$.

If $F$ is radially symmetric there is a function $f$ satisfying $F(x) = f(|x|)$. Except at the point $x=0$ you have
$$\frac{\partial |x|}{\partial x_i} = \frac{x_i}{|x|}$$ so that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x) = f'(|x|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}.$$ Consequently
$|\nabla F(x)| = |f'(|x|)|$ and thus $|\nabla F(s\omega)| = |f'(s)|$. Now integrate the $p$-power of these and apply the change of variable rule:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbf R^N \setminus \{0\}} |\nabla F(x)|^p \, dx &= \int_{\mathbf S^{N-1}} \int_0^\infty |\nabla F(s\omega)|^p s^{N-1} \, ds d\omega \\
&= \int_{\mathbf S^{N-1}} \int_0^\infty |f'(s)|^p s^{N-1}\, ds d\omega \\
&= \omega_N \int_0^\infty |f'(s)|^p s^{N-1}\, ds
\end{align*}
where $\omega_N$ is the surface area of $\mathbf S^{N-1}$. From here the inequality is trivial.

Comment: Deleting the point $0$ from the domain of integration is immaterial since it does not affect the integral. The point is that the derivative formula did not hold there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the chain of equalities in the end, maybe you mean $\int_{S^{N-1}}\int_0^{\infty} |f^{\prime}(s)|^p s^{N-1} ds d\omega$ instead of $\int_{S^{N-1}}\int_0^{\infty} |f^{\prime}(s)|^p ds d\omega$? Moreover, I don't understand why the inequality is trivial.

Comment: I corrected the error. The right-hand side can only get smaller if the integral begins at $r > 0$ instead of $0$. After that take the $p^{th}$ root on both sides.